# Is mutual information symmetric?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

Why is mutual information symmetric, meaning why does I(A,B) = I(B,A)? Isnt the definition of mutual information, I(A,B), something like "the reduction of entropy in A when given B"? P(A|B) doesnt equal P(B|A) right?

Answer (score 5):

Given the definition for mutual information

$$I(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X}
  p(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)}
  \right) },$$

it follows from rearrangement of the summands

$$I(Y; X) =
  \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y}
  p(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)}
  \right) }.$$

Hence $I(X; Y) = I(Y; X)$.

---

Edit

> "$I(X;Y)$ measures the average reduction in uncertainty of $X$ that results from knowing $Y$"

If you interpret $H(X) - H(X|Y)$ where $H(X)$ is the marginal entropy of $X$ and $H(X|Y)$ the conditional entropy of $X$ given $Y$ as the reduction in uncertainty, then it is equal to $H(Y) - H(Y|X)$ and $I(X; Y)$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Relation_to_other_quantities)).

Comment: but intuitively how does it make sense for it to be symmetric?

Comment: According to the definition mutual information is a measure of how the joint distribution of two random variables deviates from the case where they are independent from each other. For the joint distribution there's no asymmetry, so mutual information is symmetric.

Comment: @aventurin But i was told from many sources that mutual information is something like  "I(X;Y) measures the average reduction in uncertainty of
X that results from knowing Y"

Comment: I have extended my answer. Does this help?

Comment: Well back to my question: intuitively how does it make sense for it to be symmetric? given what we just said is the definition?

Comment: The intuition is the the mutual information of two variables is indeed, the mutual, common information. Once you have the mutual information of A & B and you have B, than H(B) <= H(B|A). The reduction in entropy is the results of knowing the mutual information.

Comment: @DanLevin I still dont get how "the reduction of entropy in A when given B" is the same as "the reduction of entropy in B when given A"

Comment: A & B might have different entropy. However, the mutual information among them is the same. The reduction in entropy, H(B)−H(B|I)= I(A;B)=I(B;A)=H(A)-H(A|B)

Comment: @Armon Safai: Define what you mean with intuition. Mutual information is defined to be symmetric. BTW, what is counter-intuitive when we say that the entropy of X given Y is equal to the entropy of X minus the mutual information of X and Y; and the entropy of Y given X is equal to the entropy of Y minus the mutual information of X and Y? (see my edit above)

Comment: @DaL Without just looking at the formula, it's not clear why the additional info about X due to having Y would be the same as the additional information about Y due to having X. It's not immediately obvious (at least, to me or @ArmonSafai) that predicting Y from the behavior of X is just as easy as predicting X from the behavior of Y. While "mutual" is in the name, mutual information is described in terms of going to X using Y, and so in the same way that KL divergence (which is described in terms of describing X using Y) is usu. asymmetric, the intuition for me would have been that MI is too.

Answer (score 0):

$I(A;B) = I (B;A) = H(A)-H(A|B)\\I(A;B) = I (B;A) = H(B)-H(B|A)$

Think of it like a Venn diagram, where the intersection is mutual information. Remember, if A depends on B, then B also depends on A. The information one has of the other is the same the other have of the one.

Comment: Remember that “depends” here refers to the idea in probability theory of random variables that are not independent, not to any kind of causation. (Causation could be present, however.)